# Store Custom Object Attributes as Columns in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, orm, hibernate-mapping

how can we generate table using custom object attribute as table column

```
private class CustomObject {   
    String attr1;
    String attr2;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
public class Result {
   @Column
   private  String id;

   @Column
   public CustomObject cobject;
}
```

RESULT table generate  as follow

| id | attr1 | attr2 |
| --- | --- | --- |

Comment: You're looking for `@Embedded`.

Comment: thank you @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Hibernate_User_Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) documentation:

> PA defines two terms for working with an embeddable type: @Embeddable
> and @Embedded. @Embeddable is used to describe the mapping type itself
> (e.g. Publisher).@Embedded is for referencing a given embeddable type
> (e.g. book.publisher).

So you can annotate your classes like below:

```
@Embeddable
private class CustomObject {   
    String attr1;
    String attr2;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
public class Result {
   @Column
   private  String id;

   @Embedded
   public CustomObject cobject;
}
```

Comment: thank you @dariosicily

Comment: @try_aaam You are welcome.